# How to read value from generator created by max() and comprehension list?

Tags: python-3.x, generator, list-comprehension

I try to find the max value from a list of dictionaries using comprehension list (if possible). The code below returns a generator. I can't manage to read the value from this generator. gen.next() or next(gen) will return error messages.

Of course I could easily do it other way but I try with one line and particularly to understand why I can't access value from my generator.

Thank you

```
dic = [
  {
    "a":4
  },
  {
    "a":7
  },
  {
    "a":5
  }
]
```

```
b = (max(t["a"]) for t in dic)
```

Comment: `max(t["a"] for t in dic)`

Comment: Thanks . I just found out after digging